# how to join two mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql tables. ie,

1. db_post
2. db_like

//db_post

```
id  ||  name  ||  username  ||  unique_key  ||  pub

1       Jit        jit11         unkey1         demo
2       Rah        rah11         unkey2         demo1
3       dee        dee11         unkey3         demo2
```

//db_like

```
id  ||  post_id  ||  unique_key

1          2           unkey3
```

My question is, how to mix this two tables according to `unique_key` field in table `db_post`.

//output should be like below. (WHERE unique_key='unkey3')

```
id  ||  name  ||  unique_key  ||  pub

3       dee         unkey3        demo2
2       Rah         unkey3        demo1 -> Result from table db_like
```

Comment: To mix the tables take a kitchen mixer or any other random function. What you are looking for is JOIN. There are two major types of joins INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN, here you need left join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why the answer given by @tango has been accepted, the query does not give the desire output, it returns this:

```
id  ||  name  ||  unique_key  ||  id
3       dee       unkey3          1
```

In fact I don't see how you can obtain the output you wrote in your question by joining these two tables with a single join.

Either you join using the tables using the `unique_key` column, like this :

```
select db_post.id, db_post.name, db_post.unique_key, db_post.pub
from db_post
left join db_like on db_post.unique_key = db_like.unique_key
where db_post.unique_key = 'unkey3';
```

and you obtain the first row of your desired output :

```
id  ||  name  ||  unique_key  ||  pub
3       dee       unkey3          demo2
```

either you join the two tables using `db_post.id = db_like.post_id`:

```
select db_post.id, db_post.name, db_like.unique_key, db_post.pub
from db_post
left join db_like on db_post.id = db_like.post_id
where db_like.unique_key = 'unkey3';
```

and you obtain the second row of your desired output:

```
id  ||  name  ||  unique_key  ||  pub
2       Rah       unkey3          demo1
```

To obtain both rows you have to use `union`:

```
select db_post.id, db_post.name, db_post.unique_key, db_post.pub
from db_post
left join db_like on db_post.unique_key = db_like.unique_key
where db_post.unique_key = 'unkey3'
union
select db_post.id, db_post.name, db_like.unique_key, db_post.pub
from db_post
left join db_like on db_post.id = db_like.post_id
where db_like.unique_key = 'unkey3';
```

Answer (score 1):

as per my understanding, you are asking for SQL for said problem. if its the case, then following would be join between two tables.

```
select p.id, p.name, p.unique_key, l.id
from db_post p
left outer join db_like l on
p.unique_key = l.unique_key
where p.unique_key='unkey3'
```

if my comment satisfies your problem then mark it as correct answer to help other reader in future.

Comment: Just look the question again, i need only the result for the given `unique_key`. Now it displaying all table values.

Comment: you can add where clause for given unique key, let me update my comment

Comment: Why was this answer accepted ? The query does not give the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for joining two tables

```
select a.id, a.name, a.unique_key
from db_post a, db_like b WHERE
a.unique_key = b.unique_key AND a.unique_key='unkey3' GROUP BY a.unique_key
```